# Building virtual machines with Terraform using Hyper-V provider

Tags: terraform, host, hyper-v

I'm trying to build some virtual machines using a Hyper-V provider with Terraform. I was looking for information about the host parameter that I need to add in hyperv provider's configuration. Then, I saw something like I need an Hyper-V API but I don't know anything about that and I don't understand so well what I founded. Can someone give me an example how to prepare the API or explain where can I found more information?

```
provider "hyperv" {
  user     = <User>
  password = <Password>
  host     = ????
  port     = ????
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host is referring to the machine that hyper-v is on that you would be deploying the VM to.  If that is your localhost or a remote server you would need to provide a FQDN or an IP address.  I'll caution you that this terraform provider plugin is still in beta.